# Onclicklistener of Fragments

Tags: android, android-layout

I have 3 menu tabs as Fragment1, fragment2. Two of these Fragments have listView with onClickListener other one is only a Fragment.

When the Fragment is in focus and user touches an empty space, the onclick listener of Fragmentlist reacts.:

[image]

[image]

Fragment code: one with onclicklistener

Fragment 1:

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            R.layout.fragment_genere_view,GENERE_TITLES)); 
    getListView().setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
           }

public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("package", GENERE_CLASSES[position]));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Fragment 2:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
           Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_view, container, false);

    return myFragmentView;
   }
```

Comment: please post your code also. without that difficult to tell whats happening.

Comment: Posted the code used to create both the fragments, Fragment 1 is a listview with on onclicklistener which loads when the app loads first time, Fragment 2 is a a layout, when Fragment 2 is in focus and user touches an empty space, the Fragment 1 onclicklisterner reacts.

Comment: Wish i could i add pictures to illustrate the problem in a better way. Need 10 or more reputation to do so

Comment: go on now you have rep=18.

Comment: as you can see when search tab is over the genere and if user clicks any blank spot in search tab the onclick listener of genere tab reacts though it is no where visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem in the tablistener of the Main Activity that contains the fragments. Your not dettaching the current fragment on TabDeselect listener of actionbar tabs. consider reading this: http://arvid-g.de/12/android-4-actionbar-with-tabs-example

Comment: That did heli\p. The version 11 i was using did not support TabDetach, upgraded to 14, did the trick. Thanks PaNaVTEC